# Linear transformation, change of basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Linear operator $A$ in standard basis has matrix:
$\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
2& 5& −3\\
−1& 2& 1\\
2& −3& 2
\end{array}\right)$,

Find its matrix in base $\cal F = ($$f1, f2, f3$$)$, where 
$$f1 = (1, 1, 1),~~~ f2 = (1, 2, 3), ~~~f3 = (4, 3, 3)$$

Can I just do this: $A\cal F = S\cal F ← \cal E * A\cal E$ ?

Comment: These notations aren't standardized at all, so we have no idea what you mean when you ask if you "can just do this." However, if you do it, it's very easy to check whether your matrix is correct or not.

Comment: check $\S$ 5 of https://juanmarqz.wordpress.com/cucei-maths/multilinear-algebra-cucei-2009-b/multilineal-leccion-1/

Answer (score 0):

The matrix of your linear transformation is 
$[A]=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
2& 5& −3\\
−1& 2& 1\\
2& −3& 2
\end{array}\right)$,
because with her you have calculated that
$$Ae_1=2e_1-e_2+2e_3,$$
$$Ae_2=5e_1+2e_2-3e_3,$$
$$Ae_3=-3e_1+e_2+2e_3.$$
In the other hand you will get another matrix for the basis change and it'll look like:
$$[B]=\left(\begin{array}{ccc}
1& 1& 4\\
1& 2& 3\\
1& 3& 3
\end{array}\right),$$ 
then the matrix of the linear transformation in this new basis, will be got from the calculation of $[BAB^{-1}]$.

Comment: I understand how I can get transformation matrix, but I don't know what to do with it. Multibly the matrix in standard basis with transformation matrix and I wil get matrix in base f?

Comment: the matrix that I dubbed $[B]$ is for the new basis, and the product $BAB^{-1}$ gonna give you the matrix for the same transformation $A$ but in the new basis